# Are there any code migration method(s) if I want to change from symfony 1.4 to 2.0?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony

It seems that Symfony 2 is finally stable (correct me if I'm wrong) and I wish to transfer my projects from 1.4 to 2.0.

I checked google and symfony.com but there is no info about this topic. My guess that the framework got rewritten so deeply that no automatized tool can handle this.

Any ideas or guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right, there is no automated tool that can convert your 1.4 project to 2.0, because the structure of the framework, although still MVC of course, is quite different to the 1.X versions.

You can see some of the key differences in this page of the [Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html).

Also, bear in mind that Symfony2 requires **PHP 5.3.2** or higher.

My advice would be, if your projects are finished and running in Symfony1.4, let them be, they'll be just fine, and start learning Symfony2 ;)

Comment: Indeed. I thought that I will get an answer like this. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I'll just add that "quite different" is not giving the difference justice. I developed with symfony1.4 almost a year and had to re-learn everything from scratch when I picked symfony2 up.